# Justification for Aristotle's principle of causality?

Tags: aristotle, causation, causality, principle-of-sufficient-reason, principle

> [W]hen... a potential is actualized.. something already actual must be
> what actualizes it. This is sometimes called the principle of
> causality. (Feser, Edward. Five Proofs of the Existence of God. United States, Ignatius Press, 2017, pp. 29)

What is the justification for this principle? Why couldn't something go from potentiality to actuality without any cause? Isn't this just begging the question and assuming that there needs to be an explanation? Further reading on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Feser's principle is not Aristotle's, but many ancient Greek philosophers believed in something to this effect on the basis of Parmenides's [*ex nihilo nihil fit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_comes_from_nothing), nothing comes from nothing, see [SEP, Principle of Sufficient Reason](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sufficient-reason/#PSRBefoSpinLeib). It can be thought as an inductive surmise from experience.